# For what matrices $A$ and $B$ is $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering for what matrices (over $\mathbb{C}$) $A$ and $B$ is the equation $\operatorname{tr}(AB) = \operatorname{tr}(A)\operatorname{tr}(B)$ satisfied?

Comment: In the case that $A$ and $B$ are $1 \times 1$ matrices your above formula is satisfied.

Comment: This is not a very natural condition to ask the trace to satisfy. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Even when $B=I$ and dimension $>1$ there is no way

Answer (score 2):

Even when $A, B$ are diagonal matrices, the equality is less likely to hold, let alone general matrices.